# How much inflation to expect each week?

Tags: lumens, inflation

How much inflation should I expect (per vote) to receive each week, provided that I have enough votes?

For the variables in the formula (number of lumens in existence, etc), where do I find the exact current values to plug in?

Answer (score 7):

Based on the [Stellar Core inflation operation](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/d39fc3724d961639bb7f8e91087c272b47f8f39d/src/transactions/InflationOpFrame.cpp) you can expect to receive *at least* `{your XLM balance} * 0.000190721` every `60 * 60 * 24 * 7` seconds (one week). This however does not include the additional share of that weeks transaction fees. That value however is impossible to know beforehand.

More information can be found in the [Stellar docs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/inflation.html).

Comment: I went to this website: lumenaut.net scroll down to "How Much Will You Get In Each Inflation" and put 1000 in and got 0.2064673 XLM. I then multiplied 1000 * .000190721 and obviously got .190721. Is there a possibility that your number is from 2014 and has not compounded the annual interest? 

The calculations on the site are[ your XLM balance ] / 5200 (1 week of 1% per year) PLUS [ your XLM balance ] * [ fee pool ] / [ total XLM in existence ] MINUS 0.00001 (transaction fee)

Comment: Yeah that calculator is quite flawed. The numbers I'm using are from the official Stellar Core code that is being run on actual Stellar nodes whenever an inflation operation is run. The 0.000190721 is the weekly portion of 1% of what Stellar considers to be the number of weeks in a year. 0.01 / 0.000190721 = 52.4326109867 weeks. Lumenaut is A) wrong about the number of weeks in a year and B) making an assumption about the fee pool as there's no way to know that number until right before the operation runs. This calculator will be more accurate. https://stellarpool.net/#gains